# making scatter plot with different colors for different groups using matplotlib.pyploy

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot for my data using `matplotlib.pyplot` (which is imported as `plt`) and using the following command:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (10, 6))
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X_train_reduced[:, 0],  X_train_reduced[:, 1], c = y_train, cmap = plt.cm.Paired , linewidths=10)
```

but it gives this error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must be a mpl color, a sequence of mpl colors or a sequence of numbers, not sample group
```

when I remove this argument:

```
c = y_train
```

it returns the plot but the same color for all groups (I have 2 groups).
do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The error tells you how to fix it, namely by making the `c` argument a single matplotlib color, a sequence of colors or a sequence of numbers, not "sample group".

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: yo mean instead of for example groups "A" and "B" they should be 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes and you will need as many numbers as you have scatter points.